# Why we use @Override while implementing a method from Interface ? Does it really Override the method?

Tags: java, interface, overriding, implements

While we use any method from the interface it asks us to override all unimplemented method. also we are using '@Override' annotation while implementing the method. Does it really called overriding ? because interface contains only method definition(no executable code). The interface is say,

```
public interface ITestListener extends ITestNGListener {
  void onTestStart(ITestResult result);
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result);
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result);
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result);
  public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result);
}
```

and the implementing class is

```
public class TestNGTestBase implements ITestListener{  @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
//xyz

    }                                                                                              @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) { /// xyz} @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

also why is this mandatory to override all the methods in the interface ?

Comment: yes it is overriding. And the `@Override` notation makes sure that the method is really an overriden one and would create a compile time error if the method signature of any of these methods would change and there wouldn´t be a method fitting that signature anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the method is overriding from the superclass. This notation would create a compile time error if the method signature of any of these methods would change.

Overriding is a feature that is available while using Inheritance.

It is used when a class that extends from another class wants to use most of the feature of the parent class and wants to implement specific functionality in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

@Overriding ensures the method is a correct override and gives compile time error if its not a valid override.
It is not mandatory to override all methods of an interface in a class,you need to declare the class "abstract" in this scenario.

But if you want a concrete class(which can be instantiated) to implement an interface,you will need to implement all methods of your interface in this concrete class